# Multiple reads from multiple C++ sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm working to implement a server for a Rock Paper Scissors protocol.  So far things are going really well except I have one snag I'm trying to get past.  As a total overview of the program:

1. A client connects to the server.
2. A second client connects to the server.
3. The server receives input from client 1.
4. The server receives input from client 2.
5. The server determines a winner then sends back winning information to each client.

I've wrapped the sockets in a class to allow an easier API for working with them.  The part that I'm having trouble with is here:

```
  char playerOneRequest;
  char playerTwoRequest;
  int playerOneLength = mPlayerOne->receive(&playerOneRequest,
                                            BUFFER_SIZE);
  cerr << "After player one\n";
  cout << "Received '" << playerOneRequest << "' from player one.\n";
  int playerTwoLength = mPlayerTwo->receive(&playerTwoRequest,
                                            BUFFER_SIZE);
  cerr << "After player two\n";
  cerr << "Received '" << playerTwoRequest << "' from player two.\n";

  char playerOne = toupper(playerOneRequest);
  char playerTwo = toupper(playerTwoRequest);
```

I've been using DDD to debug it and I've discovered a problem.  Let's imagine that player one sent a `R` and player two sent a `S`. After the first receive playerOneRequest is `R` after the second receive which is to player two (a separate TCP stream) playerTwoRequest is `S`.  But at this point playerOneRequest now equals `\r`.

I can't figure out why this is the case.  All my code is available in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/claydiffrient/9440848)

Comment: So the client is sending a carriage return after the letter?  You could either modify the client not to send a carriage return, or modify the server to ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What value is BUFFER_SIZE? You only have room for one character in playerOneRequest but it appears you may read more than one character from receive. Any additional characters read will be put into adjacent variables.

Comment: It was 256, but I just changed it down to 1.  That works fine now to make sure the proper variables are there. However when my loop comes around again `\r` is sitting in the buffer for each one so it just blasts through placing those in my input variables.

Comment: So you need to use a larger buffer so you get the \r in the first read. Reading one char at a time is pretty bizarre. NB This was a classic programming mistake. You should have used 'sizeof' instead of a manifest constant, then the problem could not have arisen.